# Issue downgrading MacOS Catalina to Mojave using bootable install on 16 inch MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, catalina, mojave, install, downgrade

I've just got my 2019 MacBook Pro 16 in which came preinstalled with Catalina. To use 32 bit programs, I'm trying to use a bootable install in order to downgrade to Mojave, which I've done before.

I followed the instructions provided on this site: https://www.imore.com/how-make-bootable-installer-drive-downgrade. I also went into recovery mode to access Startup Security Utility to enable bootable installs.
In the final step of holding down Option while restarting, the prohibited symbol appears on the screen (circle with line through) and my system restarts normally.

Important thing to not: I couldn't download Mojave from the App Store on my new computer, as a warning would stop me saying:

```
    Update not found
    The requested version of macOS is not available
```

So I had to download Mojave on my older computer to create the bootable install. I checked articles like https://macreports.com/update-not-found-the-requested-version-of-macos-is-not-available-fix/. But nothing seems to work so far.

Does anyone know how I might be able to either download Mojave on my new computer, allow my computer to downgrade through bootable install, or perhaps otherwise downgrade my computer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the model of Mac that you have?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I own the 2019 MacBook Pro 16 in.

Comment: You cannot downgrade a 16" MacBook Pro to run macOS Mojave as the version of macOS is unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

- [Downgrading MacBook Pro 16” to Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375649/)

The 16 inch MacBook Pro will not install Mojave. For those that are new versions of older gear like Mac Mini and iMacs, the drivers are likely good enough in Mojave so you can try using safari to download. There’s some good discussions on that below:

- [How to download Mojave now that Catalina is available?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401553/)
- [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/)
- [Mac OS X downloads do not begin, other app store downloads normal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399514/)